# Entity Framework 6 - GroupBy on navigation properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model

I am working with Entity Framework 6 (EF 6) and have the following model:

```cs
public class Engine {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Car> Cars { get; set; }
}

public class Car {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Engine Engine { get; set; }
    public virtual Purchase Purchase { get; set; }
}

public class Purchase {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Car> Cars { get; set; }
}
```

- `Engine <-> Car` (1-to-many-relationship)
- `Purchase <-> Car` (1-to-many-relationship)

How is it possible to determine which engines are purchased the most? I need an ordered list (descending) of the engines and how often they were purchased.

I have some problems on the navigation-properties and how to group/aggregate them appropriately.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        return
            (from car
                 in this.Context.Cars
                    where car.Purchase != null
                    group car by car.Engine into g
               select new { EngineName = g.Key.Name, CountSold = g.Count()})
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.CountSold)
            .ToList();
```

Also, please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19079309/1144090).