# Select Max Date items in group using Linq VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have data as shown.

```
NameA Date
NameA Date
NameA Date
NameB Date
NameB Date
NameC Date
NameD Date
NameD Date
```

I would like to have it returned as below only getting the record with the most recent date.  I am confused on the syntax of the Linq, which i started below, but am unsure as where to go with it.

```
NameA Date
NameB Date
NameC Date
NameD Date
```

Started Linq

```
Dim pciLST = _
            From p As SmartFormData(Of PCISF) In pciSFM.GetList(m_Criteria) _
            Where p.SmartForm.EmployeeUsername.ToLower() = m_Username.ToLower() AndAlso _
                  IsOpen(p.SmartForm.CompletedDate, p.SmartForm.ActiveFor, p.SmartForm.Open)
```

**ANSWER**

```
Dim pciLST = _
            From g In pciSFM.GetList(m_Criteria).AsEnumerable() _
            Where g.SmartForm.EmployeeUsername.ToLower() = m_Username.ToLower() _
            Order By (g.SmartForm.CompletedDate) Descending _
            Take 1 _
            Select _
                Name = IIf(g.SmartForm.FormName Is Nothing, "", g.SmartForm.FormName.ToString()), _
                DateSigned = IIf(g.SmartForm.CompletedDate IsNot Nothing AndAlso _
                                 Date.TryParse(g.SmartForm.CompletedDate, New Date()), g.SmartForm.CompletedDate, New Date(1, 1, 1)), _
                ActiveFor = IIf(g.SmartForm.ActiveFor Is Nothing, -1, Integer.Parse(g.SmartForm.ActiveFor)), _
                NewLink = IIf(g.SmartForm.NewLink Is Nothing, "", g.SmartForm.NewLink.ToString()), _
                ViewLink = IIf(g.SmartForm.ViewLink Is Nothing, "", g.SmartForm.ViewLink.ToString()), _
                Open = IIf(g.SmartForm.Open Is Nothing, -1, Integer.Parse(g.SmartForm.Open)), _
                Requirement = IIf(g.SmartForm.Requirement Is Nothing, "", g.SmartForm.Requirement.ToString()), _
                Archived = Boolean.Parse(g.SmartForm.Archived), _
                Id = Long.Parse(g.Content.Id), _
                Due = GetDue(Date.Parse(g.SmartForm.CompletedDate), Integer.Parse(g.SmartForm.ActiveFor))

        Return pciLST.AsQueryable()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework - select group by, select max date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073117/entity-framework-select-group-by-select-max-date). Never mind that it's C# and Entity Framework.

Comment: Please check my answer, I have working code for you

Comment: Sorry, meetings all day yesterday :( Updated question.  Linq for selecting max date should work, but unsure as to compilation error occurs.

Comment: If your comment directed to me, you need to add my id `@T.S.` in the message or write comment under my answer. Otherwise I will not get notice. I read this by accident :)

Comment: See, where you have `.SmartForm.FormName = g.SmartForm.FormName`, try `.SmartForm.FormName = g.First().FormName` - because you group by, you need to select one concrete - they all should have same `FormName` since you grouped it by `FormName`

Comment: @T.S. Okay Thanks! that makes sense there.  But is my syntax wrong above?  It keeps throwing a compilation error "Expected =" on the second . on .SmartForm.FormName = anything or .SmartForm.AnyAttribute = any variable

Comment: Is `SmartFormData` actually a collection?

Comment: @T.S. yeah it is.  I ended up using anonymous types.  Doing that while using the Linq syntax you provided initially worked like a charm.  Updated above.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is working now

```
public class NameDate
    Public Name As String
    Public D As DateTime
End Class
. . . . . 
Dim list As New List(Of NameDate)(4)
list.Add(New NameDate() With {.Name = "A", .D = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10)})
list.Add(New NameDate() With {.Name = "A", .D = DateTime.Now})
list.Add(New NameDate() With {.Name = "B", .D = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10)})
list.Add(New NameDate() With {.Name = "B", .D = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-20)})

Dim o = From nd In list _
        Group nd By nd.Name Into g = Group _
        Select New NameDate() With {.Name = g.First().Name, .D = g.Max(Function(x) x.D)}

o.ToList().ForEach(Sub(x) Debug.WriteLine(x.Name & " - - " & x.D.ToString()))
```

Here is original c#

```cs
var o = from nd in list
        group nd by nd.Name
        into g 
        select new NameDate() {Name = g.Key, Date = g.Max(d => d.Date)};
```